# Selenium - How to to click all the More buttons of each individual items to scrape the data from the dropdown

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to scrape the information on a page, but when I open the exported .CSV file it is blank except for the headings.

I'm trying to scrape the 10 results on this page: https://www.narpm.org/find/property-managers/?submitted=true&toresults=1&resultsperpage=10&a=managers&orderby=&fname=&lname=&company=&chapter=S005&city=&state=&xRadius=

I can scrape the name, company, city and state, but when it comes to clicking on the dropdown 'More' it just doesn't seem to work. (Not getting any errors, csv is just blank.)

I suspect the problem lies is this code block:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="col-md-4 col-lg-1 arrow"]').click()
```

Here is all of my code:

```
options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/vilje/anaconda3/envs/webscrape/chromedriver', options=options)
driver.set_window_size(1440, 900)

# Creates master dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name','Company', 'City', 'State', 'Phone', 'About']) 

# URL
driver.get('https://www.narpm.org/find/property-managers/?submitted=true&toresults=1&resultsperpage=10&a=managers&orderby=&fname=&lname=&company=&chapter=S005&city=&state=&xRadius=')


name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="name"]')
company = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="col-md-6 col-lg-4"]')
city = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="col-md-4 col-lg-2"]')
state = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="col-md-4 col-lg-2"]')

# Expand the 'More' button
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="col-md-4 col-lg-1 arrow"]').click()
phone = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 with-icon lighter-text"]')
about = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="col-sm-12"]')

name_list = []
for n in range(len(name)):
    name_list.append(name[n].text)

company_list = []
for c in range(len(company)):
    company_list.append(company[c].text)

city_list = []
for c in range(len(city)):
    city_list.append(city[c].text)

state_list = []
for s in range(len(state)):
    state_list.append(state[s].text)

phone_list = []
for p in range(len(phone)):
    phone_list.append(phone[p].text)

about_list = []
for a in range(len(about)):
    about_list.append(about[a].text)

# List of each property managers name, company, city, state, phone and about section paired together
data_tuples = list(zip(name_list[0:], company_list[0:], city_list[0:], state_list[0:], phone_list[0:], about_list[0:]))

# Creates dataframe of each tuple in list
temp_df = pd.DataFrame(data_tuples, columns=['Name','Company', 'City', 'State', 'Phone', 'About']) 

# Appends to master dataframe
df = df.append(temp_df)

driver.close()
```

[image: More button.]

Can anyone please help me to click all the 'More' buttons of each individual so I can scrape the data from the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click all the elements with text as **More** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.narpm.org/find/property-managers/?submitted=true&toresults=1&resultsperpage=10&a=managers&orderby=&fname=&lname=&company=&chapter=S005&city=&state=&xRadius=")
  for more in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.row div.arrow"))):
    more.click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.narpm.org/find/property-managers/?submitted=true&toresults=1&resultsperpage=10&a=managers&orderby=&fname=&lname=&company=&chapter=S005&city=&state=&xRadius=")
  for more in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='row']//div[contains(@class, 'arrow') and contains(., 'More')]"))):
    more.click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: MoreButtonsClicked]

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me. I did the import and tried both of your suggested solution, but unfortunately both give me the same response: ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-1 arrow">...</div> is not clickable at point (1218, 877). Other element would receive the click: <div class="col-sm-12">...</div> - @DebanjanB

Comment: @ViljeVisser Did you maximize the browser? Are you using the latest _ChromeDriver_ / _Chrome_ combo?

Comment: I'm using the latest compatible Chrome and ChromeDriver. I'm using a headless browser with window size (1440, 900). I tried increasing the wait time, but no luck. - @DebanjanB

Comment: I just tried it without using the headless option. The site opens and the first two 'More' buttons get clicked and then I get the Element Click Intercepted Exception. I would really appreciate your advice on this problem. Thank you in advance. - @DebanjanB

Comment: @ViljeVisser Both the locators worked seamlessly at my end. This approach basically works in majority of the cases. Let me see if I can modify the logic somehow.

Comment: Very strange that it's not working at my end. I really appreciate your effort in helping me with this. -@DebanjanB

Comment: It looks like a few of the 'more' buttons get clicked by then it clicks on this element - (<div class="col-sm-12">...</div>). Which is giving me the error.

Comment: I have figured it out. Needed to change from Chrome to Firefox for it to work. Thank you for all your help.